# SQL Pivot Table producing duplicates

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, duplicates, pivot-table

Developers,

I am new to pivot tables, and am having a little problem with duplicates.  My table, before pivoting looks like so:

**location** | **food**
Tennessee | pear
Tennessee | orange
Florida | orange
Florida | apple
Virginia | pear

Here is the code to pivot, which works fine:

```
SELECT PivotTable.location, [apple], [orange], [pear]
FROM
(SELECT location, food FROM someTable) as inventory
PIVOT
(COUNT(inventory.food) FOR inventory.location IN ([apple],[orange],[pear])) AS PivotTable
```

This produces an output like so:

**Location** | **Apple** | **Orange** | **Pear**
Tennessee | 0 | 1 | 1
Florida | 1 | 1 | 0
Virginia | 0 | 0 | 1

Which as I said works fine.  However, I added new columns for comments to my original table, like so:

**location** | **food** | **apple_comments** | **orange_comments** | **pear_comments**

Tennessee | pear | NULL | NULL | NULL
Tennessee | orange | NULL | very juicy | NULL 
Florida | orange | NULL | NULL | NULL 
Florida | apple | crisp | NULL | NULL 
Virginia | pear | NULL | NULL| tasty

Here is my altered pivot table to account for the comments:

```
SELECT PivotTable.location, [apple], [apple_comments], [orange], [orange_comments], [pear], [pear_comments]
FROM
(SELECT location, food, apple_comments, orange_comments, pear_comments FROM someTable) as inventory
PIVOT
(COUNT(inventory.food) FOR inventory.location IN ([apple],[orange],[pear])) AS PivotTable
```

This produces an output like so:

**Location** | **Apple** | **apple_comments** | **Orange** | **Orange_comments** | **Pear** | **Pear_comments**
Tennessee | 0 | NULL | 0 | NULL | 1 | NULL
Tennessee | 0 | NULL | 1 | very juicy | 0 | NULL
Florida | 0 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 0 | NULL
Florida | 1 | crisp | 1 | NULL | 0 | NULL
Virginia | 0 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 1 | tasty

So, essentially, it is creating a duplicate row when comments are added for each entry where there are multiple locations.  In the case of Virginia, there is only one entry, so the row turns out fine.

It almost seems like I need to do another pivot or something.  Can anyone offer advice on where I'm going wrong?

Sorry.  The desired output should look like so:

**Location** | **Apple** | **apple_comments** | **Orange** | **Orange_comments** | **Pear** | **Pear_comments**
Tennessee | 0 | NULL | 1 | very juicy | 1 | NULL
Florida | 1 | crisp | 1 | NULL | 0 | NULL
Virginia | 0 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 1 | tasty

Essentially, merging the duplicates into one row.

Thanks.

Comment: What should appear in the comments section when rolled up? I.e., if you have two rows for Tennessee, for Apple with two different comments, what do you want to appear in the pivoted version?

Comment: Said another way, show us what you want the output to be.

Comment: Sorry.  The desired output should look like so:

**Location** | **Apple** | **apple_comments** | **Orange** | **Orange_comments** | **Pear** | **Pear_comments**
Tennessee | 0 | NULL | 1 | very juicy | 1 | NULL
Florida | 1 | crisp | 1 | NULL | 0 | NULL
Virginia | 0 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 1 | tasty

Essentially, merging the duplicates into one row.

Comment: Btw, you should also indicate the exact version of SQL Server (I'm assuming given the Pivot function) you are using in your tags.

Comment: Update your original post with the desired output.

Comment: So, what should show if you have two rows for Tennessee, Apple with one Apple_Comments set to 'Yummy' and another set to 'Yuck'? How should the system rollup those two different comments into a single row for Tennessee?

Comment: Sorry, I should also clarify that this table is an output for one person.  I actually have a where clause in the statement limiting the output by supervisor (where supervisor_id = 10); therefore, there wouldn't be multiple comments for the same fruit.  Sorry I didn't include this in the original post, I was trying to keep it simple, but perhaps I complicated it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you have effectively told the compiler to group by the `comment` column in addition to the `food` column. There are some solutions such as rolling up the comments into a delimited list like so:

```
Select location
    , Sum( Case When S.food = 'Apple' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Apple
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + S1.Apple_Comments
        From SomeTable As S1
        Where S1.location = S.location
            And S1.Apple_Comments Is Not Null
        Group By S1.Apple_Comments
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') As Apple_Comments
    , Sum( Case When S.food = 'Orange' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Orange
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + S1.Orange_Comments
        From SomeTable As S1
        Where S1.location = S.location
            And S1.Orange_Comments Is Not Null
        Group By S1.Orange_Comments
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') As Orange_Comments
    , Sum( Case When S.food = 'Pear' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Pear
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + S1.Pear_Comments
        From SomeTable As S1
        Where S1.location = S.location
            And S1.Pear_Comments Is Not Null
        Group By S1.Pear_Comments
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') As Pear_Comments
From SomeTable As S
Group By S.location
```

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  I do want it to group by the food and comment columns.  Are you saying this is not possible to do using Pivot tables?  This would be a disappointment, as I just learned how to use pivot tables and quite like them.  Could I wrap a coalesce in there somewhere, or must I abandon the pivot table idea and go with your code?

Comment: Found the answer (utilizes the 'with CTE' and MAX functions):

Comment: ;With CTE as ( SELECT PivotTable.location, [apple], [apple_comments], [orange], [orange_comments], [pear], [pear_comments] FROM (SELECT location, food, apple_comments, orange_comments, pear_comments FROM someTable) as inventory PIVOT (COUNT(inventory.food) FOR inventory.location IN ([apple],[orange],[pear])) AS PivotTable) select location, MAX([apple]) as [apple], MAX([apple_comments]) as [apple_comments],MAX([orange]) as [orange], MAX([orange_comments]) as [orange_comments], MAX([pear]) as [pear], MAX([pear_comments]) as [pear_comments] from CTE group by location

Comment: @Flipfyre - Using Max merely masks the problem. If you have two comments for the same location and food, Max will simply pick the one that alphabetically appears last. I.e., if the two rows are `{Tennessee,Apple,Yummy}` and `{Tennessee,Apple,Yuck}`, what you will get is `{Tennessee,2,Yuck}`. You won't know that there was a second comment.

Comment: @Flipfyre - Reading through your edits, if there is a constraint that limits the rows to one row per location and food, then yes using either Min or Max will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and suggestions.  They are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (utilizes the 'with CTE' and MAX functions):

```
;With CTE as (
SELECT PivotTable.location, [apple], [apple_comments], [orange], [orange_comments], [pear], [pear_comments]
FROM
(SELECT location, food, apple_comments, orange_comments, pear_comments FROM someTable) as inventory
PIVOT
(COUNT(inventory.food) FOR inventory.location IN ([apple],[orange],[pear])) AS PivotTable)
select location, MAX([apple]) as [apple], MAX([apple_comments]) as [apple_comments],MAX([orange]) as [orange], 
MAX([orange_comments]) as [orange_comments], MAX([pear]) as [pear], MAX([pear_comments]) as [pear_comments]
from CTE group by location
```